# What is the release id while adding references to source list?

Tags: software-sources

I am following a guide to install some program in Ubuntu. It says add the following line to your source list and replace `lucid` with your current Ubuntu release:

```
deb http://tinyos.stanford.edu/tinyos/dists/ubuntu lucid main
```

Can you please tell me what is this release id and how can I find my Ubuntu id? Also, what happens if I use an id of an older or newer Ubuntu?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding external repositories to our sources we need to submit the exact Ubuntu release version to make sure that the packages are built to run on our system. For our convenience we can use the [Ubuntu Code Names](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames) there. These would e.g. be

- **lucid** for Ubuntu 10.04 LTS "Lucid Lynx"
- **natty** for Ubuntu 11.04 LTS "Natty Narwhal"
- **oneiric** for Ubuntu 11.10 "Oneiric Ocelot"
- **precise**  for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS "Precise Pangolin"

Unfortunately at present [TinyOS](http://tinyos.stanford.edu/tinyos/dists/ubuntu/dists/) only offer builds for Ubuntu up to version 11.04. Later Ubuntu versions are not (yet) supported.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
lsb_release -a
```

The "codename" line will give you the id of your current release.

Comment: Thanks, so why I need to provide this and what happens if I put a wrong one?

Comment: Easier would be `lsb_release -cs` since it'll only return the codename.